# Context-agnostic XML struct tagging

Tags: go

I would like to be able to tag my struct without it needing to know what level it will be nested into an XML document. In other words, I want to be able to write:

```
type Elem struct {
    Datum string `xml:"datum"`
}
```

And have it work for both

```
<elem>
    <datum>Hello</datum>
</elem>
```

And

```
<list>
    <elem>
        <datum>Hello</datum>
    </elem>
</list>
```

However, in order for the latter example to work (when attempting to decode into a `[]Elem`), I need to use the tag `xml:"elem>datum"`, which decodes incorrectly for the first example. Is there a way for me to define an XML tag without knowing how the struct will be embedded? See here for a simple example:

http://play.golang.org/p/LpI2vKFpNE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is through the use of an anonymous struct:

```
func Test2_DecodeList() {
    xmlData := "<list><elem><datum>Hello</datum></elem></list>"
    var list struct {
        Elems []Elem `xml:"elem"`
    }
    if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmlData), &list); err != nil {
        fatal("Test2:", err)
    }

    if err := expectEq(1, len(list.Elems)); err != nil {
        fatal("Test2:", err)
    }

    if err := expectEq("Hello", list.Elems[0].Datum); err != nil {
        fatal("Test2:", err)
    }
}
```

Example: http://play.golang.org/p/UyYoyGgL_K

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I had tried something similar, but it didn't work for an unrelated reason: http://play.golang.org/p/Nklq6nUnk9 (basically unmarshalling appears to delete the internal `[]Elem` slice and replace it with a new one, so any references you have to the original slice won't be modified with the unmarshalled data. Thanks, this was driving me crazy. Accepted, +1.